# "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" when finding Identity User

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add a test project to my solution. I've created a test project and referenced the original project.
In my test I'm simply trying to find an AppUser (Identity user).

Here's my AppUser definition:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AppUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual List<ShoppingList> ShoppingLists { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

My original project works fine!
In my app.config I'm setting the connection string to my original projects .mdf file.
However whenever I run my test I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'ImageUrl'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'ImageUrl'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
        Invalid column name 'ImageUrl'.
        Invalid column name 'Discriminator'..
```

Comment: I'm not sure enough information is provided to properly discern what the problem is.

Comment: Could you please share your DbContext as well?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I have the same situation and no clue where to begin searching...